# how to select previous row based on date

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a form where you can enter an date, now in my table i have these fields:

- id
- userid
- timestamp
- value

What I need is the previous record(/date) based on the given timestamp, I really have no idea on how to do this in MySQL.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE timestamp < :myTimeStamp ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 0, 1
```

Comment: Depends on what you mean by previous. What happens when there are two entries with the same timestamp? This query would ignore any entries with the same timestamp. If your id field is an auto-increment you could use "timestamp <= :myTimeStamp and id < :id".

Comment: You only need to put LIMIT 1 in this instance.

Comment: In my case there are no identical timestamps, good thinking though, havent thought about that either..